# Is the construction "a/an X so Y" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I often see this construction: "Who had spread such a horrible rumor?" Or "He told her a rumor so horrible, she gasped."

How about this construction: "Who had spread a rumor so horrible."?

Note: I could have written "Who had spread such a horrible rumor?" But I wanted horrible to go at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common usage of this form is as part of a "so X that Y" construction, which may already be familiar to you:

> Who would spread a rumor **so** horrible **that** it would force her to go into hiding?

This is also just a rewording of your first construction:

> Who would spread **so** horrible a rumor **that** ...

However, it can be used by itself, although this still implies some unmentioned (or *unmentionable*) consequence.  Because of this it can feel somewhat *dramatic*, even [*melodramatic*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/melodramatic):

> "Who would spread a rumor so horrible!" the old duchess cried, throwing her arm across her face in distress.